# Why pread does not guarantee that it reads all the specified bytes?

Tags: c++, linux, file

I program in C++ and found that pread works very interestingly.

pread() returns the number of bytes read. The returned number of bytes read can be different from the specified number of bytes intended to be read.

Why pread does not guarantee that it reads all the specified bytes?

Where does this limitation come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> this may happen for example because fewer bytes are actually available
>   right now (maybe because we were close to end-of-file, or because we
>   are reading from a pipe, or from a terminal), or because read() was
>   interrupted by a signal. On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set
>   appropriately. In this case it is left unspecified whether the file
>   position (if any) changes.

from https://linux.die.net/man/2/read

Answer (score 2):

> Why pread does not guarantee that it reads all the specified bytes?

Because it is designed like that.

As it's mentioned [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pread.2.html):

> Note that is not an error for a successful call to transfer fewer
>    bytes than requested (see read(2) and write(2)).

So you simply going to call that function again in such case.

Comment: so do you know why? the fundamental reasons for this behavior?

Comment: @syko It's by design. That supports I/O interfaces that deliver data as available chunks.